# How to access private variables in a Java class method

Tags: java, private-members

I am trying to access a private variable (`x`) in my method `distanceFromPoint` but it seems it doesn't work. How can I access it? My method is returning `0.0` all the time regardless of other values.

#### Code

```
public class Pointdeclare {
    private static int x;
    private static int y;

    Pointdeclare (int x_ , int y_ ){
        this.x = x_;
        this.y = y_;
    }

    int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    int getY(){
        return y;
    }

    static double distanceFromZero (){
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
    }

    double distanceFromPoint(Pointdeclare point){
        int distX = point.getX()- this.x;
        int distY = point.getY()- this.y;

        return (double) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(distX, 2) + Math.pow(distY, 2));
    }
}
```

#### Main Class

```
public class main {
    static Pointdeclare p1 = new Pointdeclare(6, 7);
    static Pointdeclare p2 = new Pointdeclare(3, 7);

    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println(p2.distanceFromZero());

        System.out.print(p1.distanceFromPoint(p2));
    }
}
```

Comment: `static` doesn't mean `const` in java!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't declare your class fields as `static`, just leave them `private`.

Btw consider using `Point` or `Point2D` native classes from `java.awt.geom` package.

Answer (score 2):

This will work better for you:

```
package cruft;

/**
 * Point2 description here
 * @author Michael
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087002/how-to-access-private-variables-in-a-java-class-method
 * @since 12/29/12 6:52 PM
 */
public class Point2 {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    Point2(int x_, int y_) {
        this.x = x_;
        this.y = y_;
    }

    int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    double distanceFromZero() {
        return distanceFromPoint(new Point2(0, 0));
    }

    double distanceFromPoint(Point2 point) {
        int distX = point.getX()-this.x;
        int distY = point.getY()-this.y;

        return (double) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(distX, 2)+Math.pow(distY, 2));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point2 p1 = new Point2(6, 7);
        Point2 p2 = new Point2(3, 7);
        System.out.println(p2.distanceFromZero());
        System.out.print(p1.distanceFromPoint(p2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared "x" and "y" `static`, which means that they're class variables, not instance variables.

Because of that, every new call to the constructor will overwrite the old values.  Thus `distanceFromPoint` always returns zero because there's only one `x` and one `y`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not due to private, instead, it's because of static. x is static. In your method, you should use x as:

```
int distX = point.getX()- Pointdeclare.x; // You could use this.x because x is static.
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you find this relevant, it doesn't answer your question directly but I was recently informed my understanding of `static` was incorrect so having just researched the topic I thought maybe I could help. `Static` variables belong to a class and not its objects, objects of a class may access a static variable but no matter how many objects of the class there are there will only be one copy of the static variable.  So I think what the people before me were saying is instead of p1 and p2 having their own copies of x and y both objects share the same x and y field therefore your value returned is 0. In other worlds your trying to find the distance between one location, it will always be zero. Hopefully that helps :-). I'm sorry I missed the first line of the main method. p2 should return a value as long as it isn't zero but p1 will not.